# AD7730 calibration failure

Tags: microcontroller, adc, load-cell, strain-gage

EDIT: The exact issue is this, the ADC has a gain register (set during internal FS calibration and again at System FS calibration) and an offset register set during system zero calibration. The updated value of gain register is not being stored in the register. When I read it during calibration mode, I see the updated value. Once I come out of calibration mode the gain register value reverts back to some previous value but offset register is set properly. I have not been able to figure out yet why the gain register value is not being stored.

[image: PCB Layout][image: AD7730 Circuit]I am using an AD7730 with MSP432 microcontroller to measure pressure using a Vishay 3 mV/V 4 wire sensor. I have used the same setup previously with 2mV/V sensors in +/- 10mV range for load and it has worked perfect. With this setup I need 0-20mV range with FS at 15 mV.

[Link to datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7730_7730L.pdf).

I have followed the calibration procedure given in the datasheet and have tried several things given below. Still I am getting wrong readings.

1. Following the procedure in the datasheet, I did internal FS (at 80 mV) then external zero and external FS (0 and 15 mV using an external calibration grade milivolt supply powered by battery)
2. Followed the procedure I found [here](https://analogdevices.telligenthosting.net/data_converters/precision_adcs/f/q-a/24670/ad7730-internal-zero-scale-calibration).
3. Followed procedure in the datasheet to do internal FS and internal zero.

After all of that, I still see either or the following problems randomly:

1. The ADC output goes to full scale at less than full scale input. (This voltage ranges between 12 mV and 17.45 mV, I tried calibration procedure multiple times and get different voltage every time. It is not repeatable.)
2. Sometimes I get 0 at zero and full scale output at full scale voltage but the intermediate readings are neither linear nor repeatable.

In both cases, the readings are reasonably stable so I ruled out noise. I have tried the same thing with 4 chips from two different batches and mounted on two different proven PCBs. Like I said the whole circuit worked fine until I tried to change the setting to 20mV range and calibrate it.

I am at my wits' end. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Code is attached. I run the calibration step by step by commenting other parts.

```
#include "msp.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "AD7730.h"
int a=0;
void ADC_loadcell_Setup()
{
 /*  this setup is for data outrate of ADC is 1024Hz,Chop mode filter enable
  * Internal full scale calibration for bipolar input,24 bit data mode,5V 
   reference,channel 1
 * Internal zero scale calibration for bipolar input,24 bit data mode,5V 
  reference,channel 1
  */

 // write to filter Register
WriteRegister(CR_SINGLE_WRITE|CR_FILTER_REGISTER,3,FR2_SINC_AVERAGING_2048|FR1_SKIP_OFF|FR1_FAST_OFF|FR0_CHOP_ON);
__delay_cycles (1000);


// Step 1:internal Full-scale calibration
WriteRegister(CR_SINGLE_WRITE|CR_MODE_REGISTER,2,MR1_MODE_INTERNAL_FULL_CALIBRATION| MR1_BU_BIPOLAR|MR1_WL_24_BIT|MR0_HIREF_5V|MR0_RANGE_10MV|MR0_CHANNEL_1);
while(!((P2IN&BIT0)==0)){} //wait for calibration complete
a++;
__delay_cycles (1000);

    // Step 2: system zero-scale calibration
WriteRegister(CR_SINGLE_WRITE|CR_MODE_REGISTER,2,MR1_MODE_SYSTEM_ZERO_CALIBRATION| MR1_BU_BIPOLAR|MR1_WL_24_BIT|MR0_HIREF_5V|MR0_RANGE_10MV|MR0_CHANNEL_1);
while(!((P2IN&BIT0)==0)){}  //wait for calibration complete
a++;
__delay_cycles (200);

   // Step 3: system full-scale calibration
```

WriteRegister(CR_SINGLE_WRITE|CR_MODE_REGISTER,2,MR1_MODE_SYSTEM_FULL_CALIBRATION|MR1_BU_UNIPOLAR|MR1_WL_24_BIT|MR0_HIREF_5V|MR0_RANGE_10MV|MR0_CHANNEL_1);

```
   while(!((P2IN&BIT0)==0)){}  //wait for calibration complete
   a++;
   __delay_cycles (200);

    // Read default register of ADC
    DAC_Result = ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_DAC_REGISTER,1);            
    // read DAC Register default value
     __delay_cycles (200);
    MODE_Result = ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_MODE_REGISTER,2);          
   // read DAC Register default value
     __delay_cycles (200);
    FILTER_Result = ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_FILTER_REGISTER,3);      
   // read DAC Register default value
    __delay_cycles (200);
    Status_Result=ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_STATUS_REGISTER,1);      // 
 //read DAC Register default value
__delay_cycles (200);
    Offset_Result=ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_OFFSET_REGISTER,3);      // 
//read DAC Register default value
   __delay_cycles (200);
   Gain_Result=ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_GAIN_REGISTER,3);      // read DAC Register default value
__delay_cycles (200);
Test_Result=ReadRegister(CR_SINGLE_READ|CR_TEST_REGISTER,3);      // read DAC Register default value
__delay_cycles (200);

  // continuous conversion mode
  WriteRegister(CR_SINGLE_WRITE|CR_MODE_REGISTER,2,MR1_MODE_CONTINUOUS| MR1_BU_BIPOLAR|MR1_WL_24_BIT|MR0_HIREF_5V|MR0_RANGE_10MV|MR0_CHANNEL_1);//|MR0_RANGE_20MV
  while(!((P2IN&BIT0)==0)){} //wait for device ready for conversion

  spi_tx(CR_CONTINUOUS_READ_START|CR_DATA_REGISTER); //read continuous data 
mode
}

//*********Software Reset for ADC*******************//
void ADC_Soft_Reset()
{
   P1->OUT &=~BIT1;                                // make reset Pin Low
   __delay_cycles (4800000);                       // wait for 100ms
   P1->OUT |=BIT1;                                 // make reset Pin High
   __delay_cycles (6000000);                       // wait for 125mS to 
stable
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is show schematic and layout photo.

Comment: I have added the circuit and the PCB layout. What I have found in the last two days is that the ADC has gain register (first set during internal full scale and again at system full scale) and offset register set during system zero calibration. I found out that when I come out of calibration mode the values of offset registers are stored but value of gain register reverts back without storing calibration values.

Comment: OK then that's a code issue

Comment: For calibration error verification, my method was to use a perfectly linear  DAC and compare Analog In-Out using a differential AMP and scope vs Input in XY mode as well as manual DC control to find regions of interest to discover ground shift error on Vref from digital crosstalk. THis way a DSO does not saturate with 2 quantization levels / cm

Comment: Just added code for calibration. I haven't even connected the system to the sensor yet. I am giving the AIN+ and AIN- pins supply from an external milivolt source. But like I said, because the gain register values are not being stored, I get full scale output at non full scale input.

Comment: I think I know what is happening. I have connected the RESET pin to my uC. But it only takes 50 ns to reset. So the ADC is resetting the registers during power on. Tomorrow I will remove the resistor on that track and give it directly to Vdd. I will update here if it works. Also there are several printing mistakes in the datasheet which were really confusing.